# Django on a Mac: Apache with mod_wsgi configuration problems

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to run a local Django server on Apache with mod_wsgi. I am running the out-of-the-box Apache on Mac.

```
hobbes3@hobbes3:~/Sites/mysite$ apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix)
Server built:   Nov 15 2011 15:12:57
```

Apache properly loads mod_wsgi.

```
hobbes3@hobbes3:~/Sites/mysite$ apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES | grep wsgi
Syntax OK
wsgi_module (shared)
```

In my `httpd.conf` file I load `apache_django_wsgi.conf` which is

```
WSGIDaemonProcess django
WSGIProcessGroup django

Alias /mysite/ "/Users/hobbes3/Sites/mysite/"
<Directory "/Users/hobbes3/Sites/mysite">
Order allow,deny
Options Indexes
Allow from all
IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias /mysite "/Users/hobbes3/Sites/mysite/apache/django.wsgi"

<Directory "/Users/hobbes3/Sites/mysite/apache">
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

My `django.wsgi` file is

```
import os
import sys

paths = [ '/Users/hobbes3/Sites/mysite',
          '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
]

for path in paths:
    if path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(path)

sys.executable = '/usr/local/bin/python'
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I can also restart Apache without any error. But when I try to visit `http://localhost/mysite`, my browser says I have a 500 Internal Server Error.

My Apache error log says (I truncated the dates and times):

```
mod_wsgi (pid=73970): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/Users/hobbes3/Sites/mysite/apache/django.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 250, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 39, in load_middleware
    for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
    self._setup()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 89, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'mysite.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named mysite.settings
```

I don't know why it can't import `mysite.settings`, didn't I include that in the `sys.path`?

The full path to `settings.py` is `/Users/hobbes3/Sites/mysite/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've included `mysite` in the path, but you've referenced `mysite.settings`. So Python is looking for a `mysite` module *within* the directories it finds on the path. Use just `settings` instead.

Comment: Wow that was a simple fix. But now I have new errors (from Apache log): `TemplateSyntaxError: Caught ImproperlyConfigured while rendering: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb`. I know my Django `settings.py` works with MySQLdb, because `mysite` works when I do `django-admin.py runserver`. If you can't figure it out don't worry. I'll post a new question. Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: This is almost certainly a Python versions issue: mod_wsgi is compiled against a certain version, but you're telling it to look into the homebrew 2.7 site-packages. You'll need a 2.7-specific version of mod_wsgi.

Comment: I added `WSGIPythonHome /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/` to `apache_django_wsgi.conf`, but that didn't seem to solve the problem. The updated error says `TemplateSyntaxError: Caught ImproperlyConfigured while rendering: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.4-x86_64.egg/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib` `Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.4-x86_64.egg/_mysql.so
`